# Unable to save images to the public directory in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, imagemagick, intervention, laravel-4.2

Hi I'm getting this error message while trying to save an image using [Intervention/image](https://github.com/Intervention/image)
.

```
{
    "error": {
        "type": "Intervention\\Image\\Exception\\NotWritableException",
        "message": "Can't write image data to path (/home/sourav/Public/master/v1.1.01/public/images/collections/Java/backgrdImageUrl.jpg)",
        "file": "/home/sourav/Public/master/v1.1.01/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/Image.php",
        "line": 143
    }
}
```

Here is the code within my function `setBackgroundImageUrl($image)`

```
$img = Image::make($image);
$img->save(public_path() . '/images/collections/' . $this->getCollectionTitle() . '/backgrdImageUrl.jpg');
```

It looks like a permissions issue but I tried `chmod -R 777 /images/collections` at it still throws the same error message.

Comment: Does the folder `/home/sourav/Public/akademe_master/v1.1.01/public/images/collections/Java/` exist?

Comment: give your folder permission to write your image

Comment: @jerodev yes the collections folder exists but the Java folder within the collections folder is created dynamically

Comment: @Imtiaz can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Can you post the code that creates the `java` folder?

Comment: try to give chmod 777 -R to your public folder

Comment: @Jerodev - $img->save(public_path() . '/images/collections/' . $this->getCollectionTitle() . '/backgrdImageUrl.jpg'); .. creates a folder dynamically.

Comment: @ImtiazPabel - I tried that but it doesn't work

Comment: Looking at [`Image.php`][1] on the master branch of the library line `139`, it shows that it is reading the extension of the file and encoding before passing it to be saved, I would debug the path there and also the data passed.

  [1]: https://github.com/Intervention/image/blob/master/src/Intervention/Image/Image.php

Comment: @8yt3c0d3 first try to save image in public root.Then use your dynamic folder to save